# Vb .net 2013 Menu Strip Control

Tags: vb.net

Greetings.  I created a Menu with ***300 + Sub Menus (ToolstripMenuIems)*** and assigned all the submenu names in a database.

When I login I want to check the submenu name in the database and if the status is no then I want to disable it rite from there.  No need to check all the menu control items.  when I try to assign values for menu items its displaying cant convert string values to toolsrip menu item. .  Please help me in this regard.

Comment: [a Menu with 300 + Sub Menus`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fvdkb.png)  Maybe the error is in the code?

Comment: @Plutonix - I'm going to get in there before you .... Raynish - Make sure you have Option Strict =ON and please post code so that we can duplicate your problem - Have a look at [mcve]